# How to detect multi screen with eglfs?

Tags: qt

```
OS: Ubuntu 18
Qt: 5.15.1 GCC x64
```

I tried

```
qDebug()<<"screens"<<QGuiApplication::screens();
```

**xcb** which shows:

```
screens (QScreen(0x55ab206fba50, name="HDMI-0"), QScreen(0x55ab206fba90, name="DVI-D-0"))
```

but on **eglfs** which shows:

```
screens (QScreen(0x55c07f8308f0, name=""))
```

backend used `eglfs_x11` cannot detect the second screen, so I tired `eglfs_kms_egldevice`, then the app even cannot enter the main function and give

> Could not open DRM (NV) device

Answer (score 0):

As far as  i know, `eglfs` does not support multiple displays

here i find something that might help:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/88111/imx6-multi-screen-use-eglfs

you might wanna try `wayland`

Comment: `eglfs` do support multiple displays, I was running my app without `wayland` compositor on R-Car E3. but  I also want to it run on Ubuntu.